# Selenium firefox profile can't load extension - python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to load firefox addon in my python selenium code.
But I am getting following error.How to fix this issue

```
Selenium version : 3.13.0
python : 3.6
firefox version : 61.0.1
```

code

```
firefoxProfile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile() 
firefoxProfile.add_extension(extension = "firefoxbinary/ublock1.16.14.xpi")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefoxProfile,executable_path="geckodriver") 
driver.get('http://amazon.com/') 
print(driver.page_source)
```

Error :

```
raise AddonFormatError(str(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.AddonFormatError: ("[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/f7/cw_7hbmn67q_db74544p0x3srxlj8y/T/tmp08r3_4os.ublock1.16.14.xpi/install.rdf'", <traceback object at 0x10332b248>)
```

I am  following this http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/faq.html

Update : There is ongoing issue https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/5069

Thanks

Comment: plugin is not found in `/var/folders/f7/cw_7hbmn67q_db74544p0x3srxlj8y/T/tmp08r3_4os.ublock1.16.14.xpi/install.rdf'` location, which is different than you specified. Try giving full path to .xpi

Comment: I am not sure why it is trying to search in above path.I am using absolute path only

Comment: seems it is trying to store or retrieve from that location temporarily same issue https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/759

Comment: it would be great if the person down voted give  suggestions to improve the question quality